# Using ARRAYFORMULA with SUMIF for multiple conditions combined with a wildcard to select all values for a given condition

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-query-language, ifs

I am using `ARRAYFORMULA` with multiple conditions using `SUMIF` concatenating the conditions using `&` and it works. Now I would like to use similarly this idea for a special condition indicating to consider all values using a wildcard ("ALL") for a given column, but it doesn't work.

Here is my example:
[image: View of the Spreadsheet]

On `I2`if have the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(not(ISBLANK(H2:H)),sumif(B2:B & C2:C & D2:D & year(E2:E),
  if($G$2="ALL",B2:B,$G$2) & if($G$4="ALL",C2:C,$G$4) & if($G$6="ALL",D2:D,$G$6) &
  H2:H,A2:A),))
```

and it works, when I enter specific values, but when I use my wildcard: `ALL` indicating that for a given column/criteria all values should be taken into consideration, it doesn't work as expected. The scenario should consider that all criteria can be labeled as `ALL`in such case it will provide the sum of NUM per year.

Here is my testing sample in Google Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c28KRQWgPCEdzVvwvXFOQ3Y13MBDjpEgKdfoLipFAOk/edit?usp=sharing

**Notes**:

1. I was able to get a solution for that using `SUMPRODUCT` but this function doesn't get expanded with `ARRAYFORMULA`
2. In my real example I have more conditions, so I am looking for a solution that escalates having more conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(A2:E, 
 IF(G2="All", B2:B<>"×", B2:B=G2), 
 IF(G4="All", C2:C<>"×", C2:C=G4), 
 IF(G6="All", D2:D<>"×", D2:D=G6)), 
 "select year(Col5),sum(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by year(Col5)"), 
  "offset 1", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  @player0 it works pretty well, except for the scenario all T* values are ALL. In this case, it generates a blank row.

Comment: @DavidLeal answer updated