# Advanced filter/configurator based on dataset

Tags: google-sheets, filter, advanced-filter

I would like help with a problem, or rather a challenge in Excel and/or Google Sheets.

What we want to develop is as follows:

We have a table of products and certain attributes. Now we want to create a kind of search function based on this table.

- Example:

*Let me give a simple example. Suppose you have as a product an apple, a banana and an orange. The characteristics associated with these are size, color country of origin. We then want a search function, where you indicate one or more preferences, i.e. size, color and/or country of origin and that based on those criteria, all products that meet these criteria are displayed.
So if you specify oblong as the size and do not specify any other criteria, it only shows "Banana. If the banana and the orange have Holland as their country of origin and you only give Holland as the criteria country of origin, it will show 'Banana' and 'Orange'. If you say country of origin Netherlands and format oblong, it again shows only 'Banana'*

See below an image of our document and how we would like this to look approximately.

[image]

Currently, there is no existing formula, because we simply do not know if this can be done and how best to do it.

The document can be accessed at:

A copy of our document with sample data:
[Document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1coavfrUvAcRI-JWQL5cEJP3yv_uOVNg3OT3o28Sc_KQ/edit?usp=sharing)

**ADDITION:**
Hi, Unfortunately I still am not able to get it to work. I am not really a hero in coding/functions. I created a bit more of a clear view in my file and also set the language of my sample file to english. You can find it here: [Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yiC-M95GDPxW9jhhXrHabynuxt4yVGK2L3zUtJXrS7Q/edit?usp=sharing)

What I actually need is just that it shows the data on 'Datasheet' if conditions on the left (parameters/value) are met, but only if they are filled. Probably easy one for you, hard to me haha Could you help me out once more? –

Comment: Hey mark, Make sure your questions contain an example and a desired outcome and your failed approach ... see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited the question to add more information like an example and a desired outcome. A failed approach is not available, as we do not know where to start. I apologize for the earlier, too-short question.

Comment: Try **Data > Create a filter**. See the [filters](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) help page.

Comment: @MarcLonsain as mentioned above, have you tried creating a filter? Or do you want a formula? If so, based on the data you have shared in the document, please specify what data you are trying to filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very generic, I will try provide here some guidelines on how to achieve it in Excel or Google Sheet based on my own experience. The approach used for Excel can be used for Google Spreadsheet, since it is based on `FILTER` function that both tools have but with different signature. For Google Spreadsheet you can also use `QUERY` that is very powerful for situation like this.

In all cases, it is a good practice to have a sheet with the input raw data (let's say `Input` tab), then in second sheet the working data of filtered data (let's say `WorkData`). This is specially relevant when the raw data is big dataset, so you don't touch the original data set, and instead you have the filtered data in a separated tab.

Both tools offer filter features in the UI or slice. This is something to consider, but using Excel/Google Spreadsheet functions, you can show the filter parameters in a more friendly manner, because you can see the parameters selected without additional click to find what filter values where selected. The approach here is based on Excel/Google Spreadsheet functions.

### Excel

Let's say you have a block of filter conditions that you want to apply to a range of data. You can use data validation list so you can select a subset of possible values for each of the filter conditions and then to concatenate such conditions logically (`OR` or `AND`) using multiplication of addition.

```
=FILTER(dataset, condition1 * condition2...conditionN)
```

where each condition is based on the filter value you want to restrict and each condition represents an array of `{TRUE,FALSE}` values all of them of the same size as `dataset` (number of rows).

I use some *wildcard* values to represent all values of the column, in my case I use `ALL`, but you can setup in a different way. In such case the filter doesn't take effect, but we want to make it work when a specific value is selected. The following trick can be used for both scenarios.

```
IF(B3="ALL", D3:D15<>"*",D3:D15=B3)
```

indicating that if `B3` is equal to `ALL`, then the condition to select all of the `D3:D15` rows is the following: `<>"*"`. Otherwise select only the rows equals to `B3`.

Sometimes I would like to consider OR conditions for a given filter condition, for example for a given filter condition, consider `value1` or  `value2` and it is represented in the filter value as a list of values delimited by comma, for example: `value1, value2`.

Here, some Stack Overflow questions I posted with answers about how to deal with that:

1. [Filter an excel range based on multiple dynamic filter conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73492445/filter-an-excel-range-based-on-multiple-dynamic-filter-conditions)
2. [Filter an excel range based on multiple dynamic filter conditions (with column values delimited)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725751/filter-an-excel-range-based-on-multiple-dynamic-filter-conditions-with-column-v)

### Google Spreadsheet

The `FILTER` function here, allows to add the filter conditions via input arguments, so now we have:

```
=FILTER(dataset, condition1, condition2...,conditionN)
```

**Note**: Keep in mind in Google Spreadsheet we don't need to add the conditions by multiplying each one of them. It is added via input argument.

here you can check some of question I posted related to this topic:

1. [Using ARRAYFORMULA with SUMIF for multiple conditions combined with a wildcard to select all values for a given condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906122/using-arrayformula-with-sumif-for-multiple-conditions-combined-with-a-wildcard-t/71906506?noredirect=1#comment127064695_71906506)
2. [Using ARRAYFORMULA with SUMIF for multiple conditions combined with conditions using a wildcard. Result by Months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71933181/using-arrayformula-with-sumif-for-multiple-conditions-combined-with-conditions-u)

In some cases it is better to use `QUERY` function.

Here, a sample file using `QUERY` statement and how to combine multiple conditions inserting `IF` in the `where` statement.

sample query on `C1` cell:

```
=query('Jira Issues'!$A:$T, "where " 
 & IF(B2="", "G is not Null", "G >= date '"
 & TEXT(startPeriod,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'") 
 & IF(B3="", "", " and G <= date '"
 & TEXT(endPeriod,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'") 
 & IF(OR(B4="ALL",B4=""), "", " and A='"&B4&"'") 
 & IF(OR(B5="ALL",B5=""), "", " and I='"&B5&"'") 
 & " label A 'Team', S 'Reporter', T 'Assignee', 
     P 'Env.', I 'Release'",1)
```

[image: sample using Query]

The raw data is in `Jira Issues` tab, the data populated is based on multiple filter conditions. I am using some *name ranges* for the filter values for a better understanding of the formula, such as: `startPeriod`, `endPeriod`, etc. You can test the actual query will be invoked looking at the result of the consolidated string of the `query` input argument of `QUERY` function.

Similarly you can stablish a `where` statement to consider whether the input parameter is empty or not. In such case, you can build a logic like this inserting an `IF` block as part of the `where` statement and concatenate the string result.

```
=QUERY(Input!A:Y, 
  "select *" & " where A " & IF(B2="", "<>'*'", "='"&B2&"'")
  "and " & " where B " & IF(B3="", "<>'*'", "='"&B3&"'")  
,1)
```

The above query for column `A` or `B`, returns the entire column via condition: `"<>'*'"` if the input parameter `B2` or `B3` were not specified. In a similar way you can add additional conditions for more parameters, repeating the third line of the query and changing the column and the parameter cell.

### Recommendations

1. Focus on a specific tool: Excel or Google Spreadsheet, even they have some similarities, you need to get familiar with the specifics of each one of them.
2. Try to start working on your specific problem, once you face impediments, do some research, usually you are not the first person facing this problem, if you don't find a solution, then post your specific problem using a sample as an extract of your real problem (in English, your sample is in other language). Generic questions like this one are difficult to get some attention.

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks so much for your detailed answer. I do understand that my question might not be that clear, and I am sorry for that. Of course I will try to improve that with future questions.

I will check on your answer in a bit and try to make it work.

Comment: Hi David, 

Unfortunately I still am not able to get it to work. I am not really a hero in coding/functions. I created a bit more of a clear view in my file and also set the language of my sample file to english.

You can find it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yiC-M95GDPxW9jhhXrHabynuxt4yVGK2L3zUtJXrS7Q/edit?usp=sharing

What I actually need is just that it shows the data on 'Datasheet' if conditions on the left (parameters/value) are met, but only if they are filled. Probably easy one for you, hard to me haha Could you help me out once more?

Comment: @MarcLonsain I understand, let me see if I can find sometime to help you with the file. I will put some comments in the file, so you can help me with some of the questions I have.

Comment: @MarcLonsain check your sample file I provided the a solution for using `FILTER` (for the first two condition, then you can add additional ones) and with `QUERY` that is fully operational

Comment: you are truly a life saver! Thank you so much for the time and effort. You provided me exactly the solution I needed!

Comment: one last question.

What if I would want one of the conditions to be like this:
If column F in the datasheet contains the value of cell B8 in my output sheet, so a parameter value, then return the value.